# i am trying to color the JPanel window Background.but i got a JPanel window without any color after execution.what error in code?

Tags: java

I am trying to colour the JPanel window Background. but I got a JPanel window without any colour after execution. What error in code?

```
package BrickBreaker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Gameplay extends JPanel {

    private boolean play = false;
    private int totalBrick = 28;
    private Timer time;
    private int delay = 8;
    private int ballPosX = 120;
    private int ballPosY = 350;
    private int ballXdir = -1;
    private int ballYdir = -2;
    private int playerX = 350;

    public Gameplay() {

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1, 1, 692, 592);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the Color needs to be capital: `g.setColor(Color.BLACK);`

if not try to use `jPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);`

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this (I am assuming you have  JFrame to which the panel is added).

```
public class Gameplay extends JPanel {

    private boolean play = false;
    private int totalBrick = 28;
    private Timer time;
    private int delay = 8;
    private int ballPosX = 120;
    private int ballPosY = 350;
    private int ballXdir = -1;
    private int ballYdir = -2;
    private int playerX = 350;

    public Gameplay() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    // if your going to override this you need to call the parent's paintComponent.
    // otherwise the setBackground would not work.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
       g = g.create();
       // g.setColor(Color.black);// you don't need this
       // g.fillRect(1, 1, 692, 592); // now you don't need this
       // But if you want to draw a red circle, you do need to change the color
       // for that
       g.setColor(Color.red);
       g.fillOval(100,100,50,50);
       g.dispose();
    }

}
```